# Como armazenar uma variável de um foreach dentro de um array

Tags: php

Como eu posso fazer para que a variável `$aluno` não seja substituída dentro do *array* toda vez que acontece o *loop* no *foreach*?

```
foreach($alunos as $index => $aluno){
    $numero_aluno = $index + 1;
    $resto = $numero_aluno % 2;

    if($resto == 0){
        $turma_B = array("$aluno",);
    }else{
        $turma_A = array("$aluno",);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"a variável $aluno não seja substituída dentro do array"_ - se eu entendi correto, você quer que a variável `$aluno` seja igual durante todo o _foreach_.. se sim, você precisa entender como funciona o _foreach_, pq esse é o comportamento certo :P https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se consegui entender exatamente o que você precisa, a pergunta está muito vaga.
Mas acredito que você quer armazenar os alunos em duas turmas diferentes.

Se for isso, no seu código você está substituindo os valores de $turma_A e $turma_B a cada laço do loop.

Se eu entendi corretamente o que você precisa, o código mais apropriado para isso seria o seguinte:

```
<?php 
// Criando os arrays
$turma_A = [];
$turma_B = [];

foreach($alunos as $index => $aluno){

    $numero_aluno = $index + 1;
    $resto = $numero_aluno % 2;
    
    if($resto == 0) {
        // Armazenando $aluno em uma nova posição no array $turma_B
        $turma_B[] = $aluno;
    } else {
        // Armazenando $aluno em uma nova posição no array $turma_A
        $turma_A[] = $aluno;
    }
}
```